# After added the user IP in inbound traffic(access restriction) of app service in azure, those IP user still cannot access the website

Tags: azure, inbound, ip-restrictions

I have an app service that restrict all IP address and allow some of the IP, and I try to add my phone IP to test this function, it is work. But for other country's IP that I tried to add, the user from those IP cannot access.

Is that something wrong of my practice?
I added the IP here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that other country`s IP address is Public IP.
Reconfirm your phone IP, that would be Public IP.

To know more about difference between public and private IP, check here:

[https://www.avast.com/c-ip-address-public-vs-private#:~:text=A%20public%20IP%20address%20identifies,a%20unique%20private%20IP%20address](https://www.avast.com/c-ip-address-public-vs-private#:%7E:text=A%20public%20IP%20address%20identifies,a%20unique%20private%20IP%20address).